# Did Seinfeld ever use his computer?

Tags: props, seinfeld

In many, if not most, *Seinfeld* episodes, a Macintosh computer can be seen in a small room at the back of Jerry's apartment.  Did Jerry or any other character ever use this computer on-screen?  If not, are there any references in the show to it having been used off-screen?

Comment: It *was* pretty rare. I think there was another instance where he says he e-mailed someone or got an e-mail, but I can't place it.

Comment: Worth noting - Seinfeld aired from 1989 to 1998.  Back then computers were significantly less relevant to daily life than they are today.  It wasn't a staple of communication for most people like it is now, and "stand up comedian" isn't exactly a tech-oriented job, so it's not too surprising that he rarely used it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Yes**, at least once. Jerry is using his computer in [The Stall](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0697785/combined) (Season 5, Episode 12) when Kramer walks in and asks to use the phone in his bedroom. Here's the GIF from the ep (I verified it myself):

[image]